# issue with using csvread in H2 database with unicode characters as delimiter

Tags: h2

I am trying to use csvread to read from the testfile attached. The file has CTRL-A (\u0001) as delimiter in between fields.

The statement I used is

```
select * from csvread('test.csv','id, name','charset=UTF-8 fieldDelimiter=\u0001');
```

Expected Output:

```
ID | Name
12 | sandeep
```

Actual output:

```
ID | Name
12\u0001sandeep | null
```

which means it is not picking \u0001 as the delimiter.

How can I handle `CTRL-A(\u0001)` as delimiter while doing csvread of a file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
select * from csvread('~/Downloads/test.csv',
stringdecode('id\u0001name'),
stringdecode('charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=\u0001'));
```

You need to use [stringdecode](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#stringdecode) because ANSI-SQL text literals do not support Java escape sequences such as `\u0001`. Then, you have used fieldDelimiter instead of fieldSeparator (see the docs).